# SharePoint Year View Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-2010, calendar, web-parts

Can we customize the built in Calendar webpart and enable the Year view in it? Or do we have any way to create a webpart that supports Year view in a calendar and be able to link it to the default calendar web part of SharePoint.

Answer (score -1):

There is no out-of-the-box web part included in any version of SharePoint (as of SP2013). I've placed my solution on my blog, here: http://thesharepointhive.blogspot.co.uk/2016/01/sharepoint-calendar-view-as-year.html

It may or may not solve your problem ... but it'll require SharePoint Designer.

Alan.